# Microsoft Edge browser won't render on HP Victus laptop running Ubuntu 22

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, microsoft-edge

I've installed Ubuntu 22 on a HP Victus laptop.  The Microsoft Edge browser will not render properly.  Both Brave and Firefox render properly.  I use Edge on a couple of other Ubuntu 22 systems with no problem, but on different hardware.

My primary display is using the nouveau driver and my external monitor is using amdgpu driver.  Both are 1980 x 1020.  The problem exists on both displays.

Is this a video driver problem?  The laptop has a Nvidia GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobile.

Edit:  Adding system info

Processor:  AMD Ryzen 7 5800h with radeon graphics x 16
VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)

Here is what the NVidia Settings tool shows:

[image: Nvidia Settings]

Comment: Brave is based on Chromium as is Edge so it’s odd that one works and the other doesn’t unless it’s connected to the version of Ubuntu your running. What’s the hardware difference?

Comment: The system where Edge works is a msi gaming laptop with GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q and two external monitors using nouveau driver.

Comment: Why do you have both AMD and Nvidia drivers installed on the system that doesn’t work?

Comment: @Ramhound The OP has the HP Victus with AMD Ryzen + Nvidia (AMD provides the iGPU). So, both drivers must be used. `amdgpu`, open-source is installed by default, no user input needed. Due to licensing issues Ubuntu by default install `nouveau` for Nvidia if users don't select the option to add proprietary drivers during installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work simultaneously with Windows, Ubuntu and Fedora in different computers. It has called my attention your question because one of mine is the same PC as yours and that problem (mainly) with Edge also started a few days ago after an update. At this time you may notice that behaviour has been solved, it is a software issue.
That has nothing to do with your gpu or drivers, it has been a bug in version 120.0.xxxx on Linux browsers based on Chromium and for some reason it affected much more Microsoft Edge; pages render like empty (some DOM objects went away).
Edge problem solved rolling back to version 119.0.xxx or moving to microsoft-edge-beta channel to get 121.0.xxx and everything looks Ok. I notice similar behaviour in other chromium based browsers but affecting just a few page components, sometimes is not noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

> My primary display is using the nouveau driver and my external monitor is using amdgpu driver.

This is wrong, likely due a deep misunderstanding of how hybrid graphics work. With hybrid systems it's one or the other for ALL outputs. And, very likely, you're using the dGPU all the time (without even noticing it) with the "bad" driver.

Your problem, with 99.9% certainty, stems from using the open-source, community, unofficial driver for Nvidia - `nouveau` - for a new(ish) card, the Nvidia GeForce RTX 3050 Ti. So, yes, a driver problem. At the time of this writing Nvidia recommends the 535.x branch for your card. You can easily install this driver version directly from the Ubuntu repositories using the Additional Drivers tool.

With the proper Nvidia driver (proprietary) installed you should be able to toggle iGPU/dGPU easily using the Nvidia X Server Settings tool (reboot usually required; if not do it anyway and don't use the "auto-detect" profile yet because it isn't stable; Linux drivers tend to lag behind its Windows counterpart). You'll be selecting between the AMD Radeon Vega iGPU - because you mentioned `amdgpu` you must have the HP Victus with AMD Ryzen + Nvidia - and the Nvidia GeForce RTX 3050 Ti dGPU.

AMD graphics drivers are open-source and already installed, unlike Nvidia's. Both card should render Microsoft Edge properly but the dGPU, again, requires proprietary drivers.

Comment: I installed the Nvidia driver with `sudo ubuntu-drivers install --gpgpu nvidia:535-server` and now Edge renders properly.  The bad news is that the HDMI port no longer works for my external monitor.  I can get an external monitor to work with a usb-c bridge, but unless I can run two external monitors from a usb-c bridge I'll be limited to one.  `sudo lshw -c video` still shows the external monitor on HDMI using the amdgpu driver.

Comment: External video outputs typically are connected to the dGPU only. So, you should change to that one whenever you need to use external monitors. How to do that is already in the answer

Comment: `sudo apt intall nvidia-settings` gives me an Nvidia Settings app that doesn't actually do anything.  It just displays some info. There is nothing about multiple gpus or switching between them.

Comment: If so you either installed the wrong driver, something that wouldn't have happened if you used the `autoinstall` option or the driver isn't loading properly due to Secure Boot. One more reason to actually install those drivers during the Ubuntu installation, as mentioned in other comments. DON'T complicate what it's simple: Open Additional Drivers and check. If there's another, non-server, driver of the same branch select it and apply; reboot. Open UEFI settings and disable Secure Boot. (...)

Comment: (...) Nvidia X Server Settings does NOT need to be installed separately. It is always installed alongside the correct driver version. Do NOT try any other method right now because you'd need to purge everything you just installed and start over. USE the Additional Drivers tool that's there for that exact purpose and does the clean-up when enabling different versions. That's all and what you should keep in mind whenever dealing with Nvidia cards in Ubuntu, standalone or hybrid.

Comment: I've had secure boot disabled.  I couldn't boot into Ubuntu if it wasn't.  Are you saying that `sudo apt install ...` is broken for nvidia drivers?  If it is Ubuntu should get rid of those repos.

Comment: No, it's not broken nor are the repos. But it isn't immune to users' mistakes. You decided to explicitly install the "server" version so don't blame the tools. And Ubuntu works perfectly with Secure Boot and it's always recommended to have it enabled. It seems you have deeper problems than what transpired from your question. Have you installed Ubuntu in legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode, perhaps? If so the first thing you should do is START OVER! Disable Legacy mode in UEFI, enable Secure Boot, REINSTALL Ubuntu properly in UEFI mode (...)

Comment: (...) making sure to select the option to install 3rd party drivers, codecs, etc. **This option automatically install the correct Nvidia driver** and prompts you to manually sign the unsigned Nvidia drivers with MOKutil.